# no connection with Google play developers console

Tags: android

Hey fellas for the last few days i read a lot about Google play developers console and I'll be happy if u can halp me out with something.

I have my game created using google cloud for 2 months and now i want to add some achievments and leaderboards to it and keep in mind the game is not realeased yet so i use my debug SHA1 key and everything i have my oath2 created in google services console and few days ago i created my app in the google play developers console. I clicked on the tab that says that i use google services and linked my app straight there.

i also dont use baseGameActivity.java so im working with Gamehelper.java directly and everything looks good just i cant connect to games.API. The weird part is that i connect to appState.API with no problem but i get problem with connecting to the Games.API.

I modified my manifest with

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

and also checked for sha1 if is the same packege name if it's the same, APP_id if its the same. Also all my id's are in different folder ids all id's are strings and i have only the numbers for the app_Id like it's suppose to be...

So there is my problem and i will be glad if anybody can explain what the heck is going on ... 
Thanks

This is the LogCat

> 06-26 09:19:11.002: W/GameHelper(3585): **** APP NOT CORRECTLY
>   CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES 06-26 09:19:11.002:
>   W/GameHelper(3585): **** This is usually caused by one of these
>   reasons: 06-26 09:19:11.002: W/GameHelper(3585): **** (1) Your package
>   name and certificate fingerprint do not match 06-26 09:19:11.002:
>   W/GameHelper(3585): ****     the client ID you registered in Developer
>   Console. 06-26 09:19:11.002: W/GameHelper(3585): **** (2) Your App ID
>   was incorrectly entered. 06-26 09:19:11.002: W/GameHelper(3585): ****
>   (3) Your game settings have not been published and you are  06-26
>   09:19:11.002: W/GameHelper(3585): ****     trying to log in with an
>   account that is not listed as 06-26 09:19:11.002: W/GameHelper(3585):
>   ****     a test account.

And then it shows me the information about my app but everything is set right and i think that there is miscommunication between google play services and google developers console but dunno why ...

Comment: I suggest you look at (or post) the logCat.

Comment: I checked my testing accounts and game id everything looks the same. Another thing i think that may couse the problem is that i connect with google in the very start of my game using googleAccountCredential so by the time i want to connect with googlePlay i already have another connection with google. It's something i made long before that and i don't want to mess with it if this doesn't work so i just left it for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bypassing BaseGameUtils and two connections to Google should be fine.

If you have checked everything carefully then this may be the cause of the problem:

"trying to log in with an account that is not listed as a test account"

A number of people (including myself) encountered this problem when we tried to use "developer" accounts which are not Google Plus enabled e.g.

[Is it possible to access Google Play Game Services API with service account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093806/is-it-possible-to-access-google-play-game-services-api-with-service-account)

Comment: Thank you mate. I got stuck with another issue right now but pretty soon i'll have to come back to this and your answer will be the very first thing i would try. I will update here if it worked or not. Thank you again!

Comment: Hey so what happened to be the issue is that I've created my credentials from google app console where I've created the game. But it happened to be impossible for google game console to "see" my accounts that're there so in the end i had to delete all android accounts from google app console and then recreate them in Google Game Console using linked apps... It's super weird for me to be that way but that's how it is

Comment: Hopefully it will now work ... I agree that you should work in developer (game) console rather than api console.

Comment: Indeed that's what i do. I use them both though. And so far it works just fine. Thanks for your response.